# VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernal service, rc = VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error. Unable to get past login screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, login

I am currently running ubuntu 32 bit on oracle VM Virtual Box. During starup, it would display the error message"VBoxClient: Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernal service, rc = VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error". Also, after I installed [This NVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/81253/en-us)(i think its the incorrect one), I was unable to get past the login screen. I can't even log into the guest user. And when i try to login using the console (control-alt f1)
, it says that my password is incorrect. Is there another way to remove the driver manually?

Comment: Please avoid asking three questions in one as we can not give you answers that will cover all issues: 1. Virtual Box is unable to access the virtual hard drive (**which host OS?**) 2. We should not install graphics drivers in the guest - it is only a virtual graphic card there 3. Are you sure the password input matches the present keyboard layout.

Comment: 1. windows 7 is the host

Comment: 2. i installed it on the root user and 3. the password is the spacebar key